# how to check undelivered email with smtp in Codeigniter?

Tags: smtp, codeigniter-3

How can i check undelivered email with smtp in Codeigniter?
If the email was undelivered [not sent] then i want to show alert box with Email send failed. How can i do that?

For example: I was doing email send using google smtp. If email address is true the email will sent and If email address is not available or fake email address, then the gmail server reply into gmail inbox. I want to get that response email from gmail inbox and show alert box ["Email send failed"] in my codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(this->email->send()) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('Success', 'Email `enter code here`sent');
} else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('Error', 'Email not sent');
    redirect('controller/method');
}
```

Comment: Place this In your view.    <?php echo $this->session->set_flashdata('Success'); ?>      <?php echo $this->session-          >set_flashdata('Error'); ?>